# Fabric Cryptogen generated cert folder structure information

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have been studying **Hyperledger Fabric** blockchain framework, running some samples and trying the get the heck of how things work exactly .

I have trying to run and study the **Build you First Network** sample from the Fabric docs .

The **cryptogen** tool helps to generate certificates for the blockchain network entities . 
Once certs are created the folder structure is like this :

[Cryptogen generated cert folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR4Ah.png)

I want to know what each folder means or the folder structure .

Thanks .